# Average precision in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
"#{subject_item.subject_item_notes.average(:value)}"
```

For example for numbers 5 and 4 it is returning "4.5". I need it to return "4.50". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use number_with_precision.

number_with_precision(subject_item.subject_item_notes.average(:value), precision: 2)

More example here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision

Comment: Yea, you are right. I just needed to include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper in my decorator.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rails `number_with_precision` helper function:

```
"#{number_with_precision
   subject_item.subject_item_notes.average(:value), precision: 2}"
```

Comment: I tried it before. It's not working. I am still getting "4.5".

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Try number_with_precision. round() is just a number -> number conversion, so of course it won't work as Ruby will just store the number as 4.5 (not "4.50") and then render it as a string on demand.

Answer (score 0):

```
num  = 4.5
puts "%.2f" % num # => 4.50
# or: sprintf("%.2f", num)
```

Google for sprintf for more info. It's an ancient, difficult and powerful method for representing numbers as strings